# May I drive in France with a Bangladeshi driving license?

Tags: france, driving-licenses, long-stay-visas

I came to France on a type D long stay visitor visa. I want to know if I can drive in France with my Bangladeshi driving license?

Comment: Are you going to study in France?

Answer (score 2):

You have a long-stay visa, and the government of France on [The official visa website for France](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/web/france-visas/long-stay-visa) says

> **Long-stay visa**
> . . .
> Whatever the duration of your planned stay, the duration of your long-stay visa must be between three months and one year. In order to extend your stay beyond the period of validity of your visa, you must apply for a residence permit at a prefecture.
> . . .

Bangladesh isn't India, but this website from the [French Embassy in New Delhi](https://in.ambafrance.org/Driving-in-France-with-a-foreign-licence) says

> **Driving in France with a foreign licence**
>
> If you come to France for a short visit (such as holidays), you can drive using your foreign licence. It must be valid and either written in French or accompanied by an official translation into French or an international licence.
>
> If you reside in France, you may use your foreign licence for one year, under certain conditions. Beyond one year, you must exchange your foreign licence for a French licence.

So, assuming the rules are the same for visitors from Bangladesh, if your visit is less than one year, you can use

- Your Bangladesh licence translated into French, or
- An international driving permit.

However, this site [Welcome to France](https://www.welcometofrance.com/en/fiche/driving-in-france-with-foreign-license) says

> **Driving in France with a foreign license**
>
> Regardless of the country in which their driver’s license was issued, holders of a “Student” residence permit will continue to be covered by their foreign license for the entire validity period of their “Student” residence permit.